# AWS Console Dynamodb scan search payload attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

when I scan the aws dynamodb with the attribute name as "Asset_Name" string equals "MakingofaMusicVideo_HD", I am not getting any hits. But the payload contains the field. What's the best way to search for quick search.

Are there any other tools or projects which has a ux that enables users to search quickly?

`"Asset_Name": {"S": "MakingofaMusicVideo_HD"}`

Below is the payload in dynamodb

````
  "payload": {
    "M": {
      "CableLabArray": {
        "M": {
          "ADI": {
            "M": {
              "Metadata": {
                "M": {
                  "__custom:APP_DATA:2": {
                    "M": {
                      "_attributes": {
                        "M": {
                          "App": {
                            "S": "MOD"
                          },
                          "Value": {
                            "S": "CableLabsVOD1.1"
                          },
                          "Name": {
                            "S": "Metadata_Spec_Version"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "AMS": {
                    "M": {
                      "_attributes": {
                        "M": {
                          "Asset_ID": {
                            "S": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                          },
                          "Version_Minor": {
                            "S": "1"
                          },
                          "Description": {
                            "S": "Making of a Music Video"
                          },
                          "Provider_ID": {
                            "S": "hs90s.ca"
                          },
                          "Creation_Date": {
                            "S": "2020-04-05"
                          },
                          "verb": {
                            "S": "EMPTY"
                          },
                          "Product": {
                            "S": "MOD"
                          },
                          "Version_Major": {
                            "S": "1"
                          },
                          "Asset_Name": {
                            "S": "MakingofaMusicVideo_HD"
                          },
                          "Asset_Class": {
                            "S": "package"
                          },
                          "Provider": {
                            "S": "HS90s"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

While DynamoDb supports storing complex attributes (e.g. maps, lists, sets, any combination of these), it does not offer search capabilities across complex attributes.  You either need to store it as a top level attribute, or work it into the primary key.